# Как при наведении на карту изображений изменить её цвет?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Есть изображение. На нем определил участок (карта изображений).

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при наведении на этот участок, он становился красным, например?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [jquery mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

Comment: Вот мой код. Для какого тега использовать jquery mouseover?

    <map id="imgmap201282416459" name="25">
        <area shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="123,358,350,438" href="http://www.ya.ru" target="" />
    </map>
    <img src="25.jpg" usemap="#25" />

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById('imgmap201282416459').addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    document.getElementById('imgmap201282416459').style.backgroundColor = 'Цвет_при_наведении';
}, false);

document.getElementById('imgmap201282416459').addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    document.getElementById('imgmap201282416459').style.backgroundColor = 'Цвет_при_отводе_мыши_от_элемента';
}, false);
```

И не нужны никакие jQuery :)

Comment: Не работает((

Comment: Куда вы вставили код? Какие ошибки выдаёт в консоли?

Comment: у вас работает? можете скинуть мне ващ код, который работает, если не трудно